# Running multiple instances of nodejs server for scaling

Tags: node.js

I am running a nodejs server on port 8080, so my server can only process one request at a time.
I can see that if i send multiple requests in one single shot, new requests are queued and executed sequentially one after another.

What I am trying to find is, how do i run multiple instances/threads of this process. Example like gunicorn for python servers. Is there something similar, instead of running the nodejs server on multiple ports for each instance.

I have placed nginx infront of the node process. Is that sufficient and recommended method.

```
worker_processes auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile 1100;
events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}

pid  /var/run/nginx.pid; 
http {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        access_log /dev/null;
        error_log /dev/null;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually, you would just use a reverse proxy / load balancer in front and then serve your application multiple times in the back.

Comment: @poke I had placed nginx infront of node process, is that sufficient. I am yet to test it

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**First off, make sure your node.js process is ONLY using asynchronous I/O.**  If it's not compute intensive and using asynchronous I/O, it should be able to have many different requests "in-flight" at the same time.  The design of node.js is particularly good at this if your code is designed properly.  If you show us the crux of what it is doing on one of these requests, we can advise more specifically on whether your server code is designed properly for best throughput.

**Second, instrument and measure, measure, measure.**  Understand where your bottlenecks are in your existing node.js server and what is causing the delay or sequencing you see.  Sometimes there are ways to dramatically fix/improve your bottlenecks before you start adding lots more clusters or servers.

**Third, use the [node.js cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).**  This will create one master node.js process that automatically balances between several child processes.  You generally want to creates a cluster child for each actual CPU you have in your server computer since that will get you the most use out of your CPU.

**Fourth, if you need to scale to the point of multiple actual server computers, then you would use either a load balancer or reverse proxy such as nginx to share the load among multiple hosts.**  If you had a quad core CPUs in your server, you could run a cluster with four node.js processes on it on each server computer and then use nginx to balance among the several server boxes you had.

Note that adding multiple hosts that are load balanced by nginx is the last option here, not the first option.

Comment: It looks to me as if the most important thing you said here is to use the cluster module, because without that Node.js will only ever utilize one CPU core.

Comment: @jfriend00 thank you for the detailed answer. My server is asynchronous. I am calling a external script with `child_process.exec` which is also asynchronous. I think cluster module is a good practice I will try it.

Comment: If you're running child processes asynchronously, you should be able to handle a bunch of requests in flight at the same time unless the thing you're running the child process is forcing serialization.

Comment: Also be careful with the cluster module if you're already using child processes for lots of your processing.  You don't really want to end up with a whole lot more processes than you have CPUs as that can just lead to extra context switching for the OS.

Comment: @Craig - Well, I'd argue that the most important thing is to make sure you're using only asynchronous I/O because one synchronous I/O call can block the single node.js Javascript thread.  But after that, and with an understanding of where your bottlenecks are, you  do often want to get multiple CPUs involved.  There are scalability cases, where the bottleneck is a database that every request is consulting and what you really need to do is find a way to speed up the database access (caches, performance tuning, better host, faster disk, etc...) rather than immediately jump to clustering.

Comment: @jfriend00 I would argue in turn that, while you're totally correct about finding ways to optimize the database access, you're still dealing with a blocking operation that is *functionally* no different than anything else asynchronous processing helps with. For example, from the standpoint of your running code, what does it matter if the blocking op is file access or database access? Same difference. But to *really* scale (horizontal scalability), which is the root question here, you need multiple CPU's involved and Node.js just can't do that without help.  ;-)

Comment: Having said that!  Yes, running asynchronously is absolutely vital.

Comment: @Craig - I wasn't talking about synchronous calls to a database.  I was talking about asynchronous calls to a database, but a database itself that can't effectively handle multiple calls to it very well, thus creating slow responding asynchronous calls.  That's a different problem to diagnose and solve than using synchronous file I/O in your own Javascript.  You only NEED multiple CPUs if the node.js CPU is actually a bottleneck which it often is not because of how effectively node.js handles async I/O.

Comment: @Craig - A node.js request handler that is predominantly doing I/O (which is pretty common) may not actually saturate a single CPU even with lots of simultaneous requests in which case clustering wouldn't help much.  But, certainly if you have much CPU intensive code, you will want to cluster.  That's why my #2 item is to measure to understand where your bottlenecks are.  One simple measurement is to apply some load to your server and then simply look at the CPU usage of your node.js process.

Comment: @jfriend00 A database server can handle multiple concurrent calls **extremely** well. This is what database servers do. When I say extremely well, I mean there are super smart engineers working on those database engines who are so busy thinking constantly about performance and concurrency optimizations that some of them can't be bothered to find two socks that match in the morning, but they can program circles around the majority of other hacks out there. What on earth are you talking about and where are you getting your information?

Comment: @Craig - Yes, a good database, properly deployed on the right hardware can do that really well.  But everyone does not necessarily start out with all of the above.  And, there are some database operations that can be forced to be serialized because of what they are doing to the database (if all requests are updating the same value in the database, for example).

Comment: @Craig - Let me summarize with something you would probably agree with.  If your node.js server never gets anywhere near 100% CPU utilization, you probably won't benefit a lot from clustering or load balancing to multiple servers - your bottleneck is probably elsewhere.   If your node.js process is anywhere near 100% CPU utilization and you have other CPUs with spare cycles, then clustering will probably help.

Comment: We're going to get bumped to a chat. ;-) Databases, as I'm sure is the case with Node.js, get used by all sorts with varying degrees of efficiency, for sure. Persistent connections (connection pooling) is a vital strategy, as is effective index design, well-crafted queries and (dare I say it) very careful use of ORM's, which tend to be bloated and not to produce the most efficient SQL possible.

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm fairly agreeable with your last statement, with the caveat being that there may be multiple factors in play causing long waits and preventing the CPU from approaching saturation, even including lower level issues like processor cache misses, depending. However; yes, in general, unless the CPU is taxed, spreading processing across more CPU's is unlikely to help.

Comment: @Craig - I'm in agreement with your note about using databases efficiently too.  At scale, proper use of databases and the ability to maximize performance of a database is a specialty all unto itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 I heartily agree with your item #2 about profiling the code, too, and the importance of really understanding what asynchronous processing is and utilizing it to the fullest. A CPU sitting around waiting for something else to happen isn't being put to very good use!

Answer (score 3):

Like @poke said, you would use a reverse proxy and/or a load balancer in front.

But if you want a software to run multiple instances of node, with balancing and other stuffs, you should check pm2

http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: Here is the specific cluster article for a web server: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/

Answer (score 0):

Just a point to be added here over @sheplu, the `pm2` module uses the node cluster module under the hood. But even then, pm2 is a very good choice, as it provides various other abstractions other than node cluster.

More info on it here: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/pm2-doc-single-page/