# Managing more number of server request in node js API

Tags: node.js, api, server, request

In my mobile app i am using node js API & it is like a commercial app. Heart of the app is video upload. When users uploading video, For example if it reaches 100 000 request at time, how to handle all the request without any traffic congestion in node js API. How to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Using a load balancer and running multiple instances of the app is recommended. Since node is a single-threaded application, you need to run multiple instances to make the most of the processor.

Comment: Thanks Sachin. Need to run multiple instance means?

Comment: Multiple instances means running the same app multiple times.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415102/running-multiple-instances-of-nodejs-server-for-scaling do check this link I believe this will solve your queries on this subject :)